# Fastest way to get petty/lesser souls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find lots of petty creatures to charge my soul gems?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/where-can-i-find-lots-of-petty-creatures-to-charge-my-soul-gems)

So i have been enchanting a lot recently and have discovered Souls can no longer be stolen from Summoned creatures which is how i did it in oblivion. so is there another easy way to get a lot of low level souls or will i be forced to go skeever hunting?